# How can you define a type for onSubmit in a Typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Within my React app I have an interface in which I also specify the onSubmit method optionally and with the any type (which I want to avoid). So I'm looking for a way to define a type for the onSubmit method.

This is my interface:

```
export interface CustomInterface {
  product?: ProductClass;
  loggedInUser: UserClass;
  headerTitle?: (s: string) => any;
  onSubmit?: any; // Here I need a better type
}
```

How can I optimize this interface?

Comment: I'm assuming onSubmit is a callback, given the naming convention. You've already used a function type for headerTitle, is there a reason you can't do that again?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, but the headerTitle returned a simple string. OnSubmit does a little more than that, doesn't it?

Comment: We have no idea, we can't see how it's used. It's presumably going to be a void function that takes some data, but we can't tell you what shape that data will have.

Comment: In my case, the onSubmit method is passed on to two other parent components and calls a handler in the parent, in which actions are dispatched.

Comment: We'd need to know its signature and return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to do something like this:

```
export interface CustomInterface {
  product?: ProductClass;
  loggedInUser: UserClass;
  headerTitle?: (s: string) => any;
  onSubmit?(): void;
}
```

Or lets say onSubmit function needs an string param:

```
export interface CustomInterface {
  product?: ProductClass;
  loggedInUser: UserClass;
  headerTitle?: (s: string) => any;
  onSubmit?(s: string): void;
}
```

This you declare onSubmit has type function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export interface CustomInterface {
  product?: ProductClass;
  loggedInUser: UserClass;
  headerTitle?: (s: string) => any;
  onSubmit?: (data:Define your type here like string,boolean and so on)=>void // Here I need a better type
}
```